# PIL: Paste image over a transparent image without destroying background pixels

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to use PIL to combine two images with a heart image in the middle, but it always removes pixels from behind itself and replaces them with complete transparency, destroying the images below it. How do I paste/overlay an image to a specific spot on the image without doing this?

Current code:

```
heart = Image.open("Heart.png")
shrimp = Image.open("Shrimp_Jackson.jpg")
bg = Image.open("bg.png").resize((400,250))

bg.paste(shrimp, (0,0))
bg.paste(shrimp, (200,0))
bg.paste(heart, (60, 0))
bg.save("Output.png")
```

The result:
[image: This happens]

Comment: `bg.paste(heart, (60, 0), mask=heart)`, if `heart` has a proper alpha channel (for the white background).

Comment: @HansHirse `ValueError: bad transparency mask`
How do I make sure it has a proper alpha channel? I don't want a background, transparent if any.

Comment: @HansHirse Okay I created a new heart image using an image editing program and used the mask like you said and that worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You heart probably doesn't have a transparent background, it has only white colored background.

Download [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php), then convert white non-transparent background that you have to transparent one using magick command:

```
magick convert heart.png -transparent white heart2.png
```

Then use this `heart2.png` in your code as @HansHirse suggested `bg.paste(heart, (60, 0), mask=heart)`.